# <ParseException> Unexpected characters ($F[0] = (shift @F) .".$F[0]"; $, = ":"; print @F;'']

Tags: parsing, yaml

This is the yaml file:

```
tasks:
    test: {include: [bash_exec], args:['-c', 'state --m=4 in=in4.db | cppextract -f , -P NEW_MODEL /stdin Id Date {a,b,b2}{c,d}L {d1,d2,d3,d4}{x,}y | perl -lane '$F[0] = (shift @F) .".$F[0]"; $, = ":"; print @F;' | state2 --id=Id.Date wq.db -'], answer: '{{out}}/utestt.csv', n: 5, cols: [f,k]}
```

When parsed, it yields the following error:

> Unexpected characters ($F[0] = (shift @F) .".$F[0]"; $, = ":"; print @F;'']

This command

```
state --m=4 in=in4.db | cppextract -f , -P NEW_MODEL /stdin Id Date {a,b,b2}{c,d}L {d1,d2,d3,d4}{x,}y | perl -lane '$F[0] = (shift @F) .".$F[0]"; $, = ":"; print @F;'
```

provides right output on linux command line but throws yaml parser exception when running through yaml.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's untangle the YAML file in a more readable format:

```
tasks:
  test: {
    include: [bash_exec],
    args:['-c', 'state --m=4 in=in4.db | cppextract -f , -P NEW_MODEL /stdin Id Date {a,b,b2}{c,d}L {d1,d2,d3,d4}{x,}y | perl -lane '$F[0] = (shift @F) .".$F[0]"; $, = ":"; print @F;' | state2 --id=Id.Date wq.db -'],
    answer: '{{out}}/utestt.csv', n: 5, cols: [f,k]
  }
```

The first problem is `args:[`; YAML requires you to separate a mapping value from the key (unless the key is a quoted scalar). Let's do that:

```
tasks:
  test: {
    include: [bash_exec],
    args: [
      '-c',
      'state --m=4 in=in4.db | cppextract -f , -P NEW_MODEL /stdin Id Date {a,b,b2}{c,d}L {d1,d2,d3,d4}{x,}y | perl -lane '
      $F[0] = (shift @F) .".$F[0]"; $, = ":"; print @F;' | state2 --id=Id.Date wq.db -'
    ],
    answer: '{{out}}/utestt.csv', n: 5, cols: [f,k]
  }
```

This makes it obvious what happens: You end the single-quoted scalar started with `'state` right before the `$` symbol. As we are in a YAML flow sequence (started by `[`), the parser expects a comma or the end of the sequence after that value. However, it finds a `$` which is what it complains about.

Now obviously, you don't want to stop the scalar before the `$`; the `'` is supposed to be part of the content. There are multiple ways to achieve this, but the most readable way is probably to define the value as a block scalar:

```
tasks:
  test:
    include: [bash_exec]
    args:
    - '-c'
    - >-
      state --m=4 in=in4.db | cppextract -f ,
      -P NEW_MODEL /stdin Id Date {a,b,b2}{c,d}L {d1,d2,d3,d4}{x,}y |
      perl -lane '$F[0] = (shift @F) .".$F[0]"; $, = ":"; print @F;' |
      state2 --id=Id.Date wq.db -
    answer:
    - '{{out}}/utestt.csv',
    - n: 5
    - cols: [f, k]
```

`>-` starts a flow scalar, which can span multiple lines, and the linebreaks will be folded into a space character. Note that I removed the surrounding flow mapping (`{…}`) and replaced it with a block mapping to be able to use a block scalar in it.

I also changed `answer` to be a sequence which it is not currently, but it looks like it should be (it is also erroneous in the YAML you show).

Comment: I removed the comma in '{{out}}/utestt.csv', and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much